# Excel function to provide non-empty and unique results from a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula (would need to fit in one cell) that will check cells in the row for non-empty cells, and then also check if those values are the same. If they are the same, just return the result. If they're different, return a concatenated list of the results.

I started with a basic formula to just return results if the cells are not empty, but it doesn't consider where cells are the same or different yet.

```
=IFNA(IFS(A2<>"",A2,B2<>"",B2,C2<>"",C2,D2<>"",D2),"No Number Identified")
```

Example dataset would be:

```
24 - - -
- - 36 36
- 12 11 -
- - - -
9 - - 9
```

I tried this manually, but quickly gave up due to all the different conditions (1 AND 2 AND 3 match, 1 AND 2 AND 4 match, etc.). Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With office 365 we can use TEXTJOIN and UNIQUE:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(A1:D1,TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is such a simple solution... thank you so much! I do have office 365, so that will work.